# How can I prevent the address bar in Safari iOS from reappearing when a dialog is open, similar to the functionality on Airbnb?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to prevent the scrolling of the body element in the background when modals or overlays are opened, similar to what's implemented on Airbnb's website. Here's the method I've been using:

#### Opening a Modal

I add the `locked` class to either the `body` or `html` element:

```
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.locked {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Then, I use `scrollTop` to update the CSS `top` value, which keeps the current position in view.

#### Closing a Modal

Upon closing the modal, I remove the `locked` class and restore `scrollTop`.

---

This method has been generally successful, but there is an issue on iOS where the address bar reappears when the view is locked, causing a jarring jump in the content.

Interestingly, Airbnb seems to have overcome this issue without apparent deviation from this method.

**What is the solution to prevent the reappearing address bar on mobile browsers, thereby eliminating the content jump?**

---

Here is a visual representation of the current state when I open a dialog:

[image]

What I aim to achieve is demonstrated below:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is related to your code? It really seems more like a browser thing to me, that you can't exactly control.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49146/can-i-hide-the-toolbar-in-safari-while-in-full-screen-mode hmm i found this there is an code snipped as answer maybe this helps.

Comment: Please provide your code to reproduce the issue!

Comment: Tried to reproduce on Mac/Safari.  
Went to airbnb.de, opened the modal, still saw the browser toolbar.  
[View screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXqaO.png)  
Could you clarify the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried at this problem for a bit and believe I have a viable solution.

To prevent the reappearing pop-up of the address bar (which seems to be the issue if I understood you correctly) I would try eliminating the content jump(ing).

**Possible Fix:**

**1**. CSS: try using the 'position fixed' property. For this a rework of the '.locked' class is needed.

**2**. JS: Here I would (this is in combination with the CSS in [1.]) lock the scroll position --> 'window.scrollTo' which would lead to there not being any content jump.

If this is still unclear I am more than happy to fiddle around with the CSS & JS [Scripts] and show what I mean.

All the best,

Jonasz

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set the attribute overflow: hidden; to the body right before showing the popup, and then remove it when you close it. The scroll position won't change, and the page cannot be scrolled.

If you need to scroll the popup, just put it inside a fixed container with 100vh as height, and set its overflow-y attribute to "auto".